# How to use line_profiler to profile all modules in a package?

Tags: python, profiling, line-profiler

`line_profiler` is a great Python package to find performance bottlenecks. The only complication when using it is that we have to specify each profiled module one by one on the command line:

```
%lprun -m toppkg.pkg1.module11 -m toppkg.pkg1.module12 ... -m toppkg.pkgN.moduleNK my_entry_point()
```

This can be a tedious task in a project of tens of thousands of line.

I wonder if anyone knows an automated approach, where we can specify all sub-packages and modules below a particular package like:

```
%mylprun -p toppkg my_entry_point()
```

Comment: one quick hack: `find toppkg -name '*.py' | grep -v __init__.py | cut -d. -f1 | tr / . | sed 's/^/-m /' | tr '\n' ' '`